# Find the maximum every 10 rows in a particular column and print the entire row

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I would like to find the maximum value in the column no. 5 (Determine) for every 10 rows and then print the corresponding entire row. For eg. in the first 10 rows, the maximum value in the 5th column is '1.1824' and the corresponding entire row is "10_M62    6:            3.0561   405.69   1.1824". I want to find the maximum value in the 5th column for every 10 rows and then print the entire column like show above.

I tried the following command, it works for first 30 rows after which it gives wrong answers. I am not sure what I am missing. Kindly help me.

```
awk 'm<$10{m=$10;n=$5" "$2$3 $4" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9} !((NR+2)%10){print $1,n,m;m=n=""}'
```

Please let me know if I am not clear. I have given the sample list below.

```
Name      No.           Value1   Value2   Determine
 
10_M62    1:            2.4578   504.44   0.0013  
10_M62    2:            2.6155   474.03   0.0010  
10_M62    3:            2.8581   433.80   0.0418  
10_M62    4:            2.9552   419.54   0.3863  
10_M62    5:            2.9809   415.93   0.1014  
10_M62    6:            3.0561   405.69   1.1824  
10_M62    7:            3.3083   374.77   0.0719  
10_M62    8:            3.5159   352.63   0.0242  
10_M62    9:            3.6366   340.94   0.0023  
10_M62   10:            3.6553   339.19   0.0049  
11_M63    1:            1.9677   630.10   0.0075  
11_M63    2:            2.3544   526.62   1.8099  
11_M63    3:            2.7363   453.12   0.0028  
11_M63    4:            2.7437   451.88   0.0044  
11_M63    5:            2.8913   428.81   0.0569  
11_M63    6:            2.9497   420.32   0.3310  
11_M63    7:            2.9688   417.63   0.0889  
11_M63    8:            3.0038   412.76   0.0330  
11_M63    9:            3.0792   402.65   0.2730  
11_M63   10:            3.0805   402.48   0.0914  
...
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box even if your input values are all negative and/or your input is not an exact multiple of 10 lines and no matter how many blank lines are between your header line and your data:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { print; next }
!NF { next }
(++numLines) % 10 == 1 {
    printf "%s", maxLine
    maxVal = $5
    maxLine = ""
}
$5 >= maxVal {
    maxVal = $5
    maxLine = $0 ORS
}
END { printf "%s", maxLine }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Name      No.           Value1   Value2   Determine
10_M62    6:            3.0561   405.69   1.1824
11_M63    2:            2.3544   526.62   1.8099
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I sincerely appreciate your effort.

Comment: You're welcome. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.